# imgur API registration error : ERROR: Bad website scheme. Did you forget 'http://' or 'https://'?

Tags: imgur

I was trying to register application on [imgur API](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient) and folling the [imgur API docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#intro) but it keep giving error

> ERROR: Bad website scheme. Did you forget 'http://' or 'https://'?

I have already tried to change all required fields but unable to move forward.

[image: imgur API Register an Application Page with Error]

Answer (score 2):

You have "alphabet and number images" for your "Application website" but that's not a URL. You should put that in the "Description".